# JQGrid not showing data. Tried hard no success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Problem is that I can not see any row in the Grid. No matter how hard I tried but no success. FireBug is showing data. May be the problem is Column?

**Why I can not see the Data?**

Note: if I use array and bind it to Grid than I see the Array data. See at the bottom for local binding.

I am using latest JQGrid js. I think version is 4.1.1. Downloaded today.

****Jason Response
-------------------****

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","account number","First Name"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","account number1","First Name1"]}]}
```

****Razor Page
-----------------------------****

```
     <table id="list"></table> 
            <div id="pager"></div> 

        <link href="/Content/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/custom-theme/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid/sandbox-grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetGrids(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            var query = from e in _form.All() select e;
            var count = query.Count();

            var result = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = page,
                records = count,
                rows = query.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.AccountNumber, x.FirstName })
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                id = x.Id,
                                cell = new string[] {x.Id.ToString(),x.AccountNumber,x.FirstName}
                            }).ToArray(),
            };

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GetGrids/',
            mtype: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Account Number', 'Lastname'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 200 },
                { name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', width: 300 },
                { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 100 }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'Id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Pay Your Bill"
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });
```

**Local Binding is working
---------------------------------**

```
var mydata = [
                { Id: "1", name: "test", AccountNumber: "note", LastName: "1sdfd sdfsdf00" },
                { Id: "2", name: "test2", AccountNumber: "note2", LastName: "2sdf sdfdf00" }

            ];

 data: mydata,

datatype: "local",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the main error in the code which you use is

```
dataType: 'json'
```

instead of

```
datatype: 'json'
```

Because the `dataType` are unknown by jqGrid, the default value `datatype: 'xml'` will be used.

**UPDATED**: I recommend you always implement the `loadError` event handler. See the UPDATED part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) which contain the demo with [the VS2008 project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) or [the VS2010 project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) which is modification of [the Phil Haack demo](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) which you use.

Comment: Thanks man. I feel stupid :( . Worked. I will see reference posts.

Comment: @pirzada: You are welcome! It's a standard problem and almost everybody who used `jQuery.ajax` do the error once.